# Does Vec<T> auto convert to [T]?

Tags: rust, vector, slice

Consider this code:

```rust
fn funA() {
    let v1: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    funB(&v1);   // question_A
    v1.iter();   // question_B
}

fn funB(slice: &[i32]) {
    // slice type is &[i32] by sure
}
```

I'm confused because `funB` requires type `&[i32]`, while caller using type `&Vec<i32>`. Here is part of invoke stack, I can see there is kind of `deref` and `as_ptr` actions, but not sure how it works.

```
core::ptr::mut_ptr::<impl *mut T>::is_null (@core::ptr::mut_ptr::<impl *mut T>::is_null:42)
alloc::vec::Vec<T,A>::as_ptr (@<alloc::vec::Vec<T,A> as core::ops::deref::Deref>::deref:19)
<alloc::vec::Vec<T,A> as core::ops::deref::Deref>::deref (@<alloc::vec::Vec<T,A> as core::ops::deref::Deref>::deref:11)
hello_cargo::funA (/Users/path-to-hello_cargo/src/main.rs:15)
...
main (@main:12)
start (@start:639)
```

Does it auto-convert? Is it "optimized" by the compiler? What's the difference to [`Vec::as_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by how a vec could call an iter...on itself? Remember, a `Vec` will often act as a slice when referenced, so it has full access to all those slice functions, including `iter()`.

Comment: Don't forget Rust has a lot of `Into`, `AsRef` and `Deref` traits happening in the background which can give seemingly magical capabilities to simple references.

Comment: It's the `Deref` trait. Read [this chapter of The Book about Deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html)

Comment: @FZs Thanks, I had not read the Deref chapter yet. Now, I understand how it works , "Vec implements the Deref trait, which allows Vec<T> values to be treated like references." The `deref` of Deref impl for Vec<T> has a slice return type `fn deref(&self) -> &[T]`

Comment: @Seven Yes, that's right! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `Deref` coercion

```
/// Vec<T> implements Deref as follows
impl Deref for Vec<T> {
    type Target = &[T];
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target;
}

// meaning you can call
let vector: Vec<T> = ...
let slice: &[T] = vector.deref();

// Rust can call .deref() automatically whenever needed (coercion)
```

You can read about it more here

https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html